# Azure Service Tags: region names in ServiceTags_Public_*.json are different from region names in Get-AzLocation?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I want to automate the process of updating firewall inbound ACL's with the frequently changing ip addresses of Azure / Microsoft services. So I regularly need an up-to-date list of the subnets / address prefixes these services use. Most of the time, I get around in PowerShell just fine with `Get-AzNetworkServiceTag`. But in this case, I need the ip's of Azure DevOps Microsoft-hosted Agents and they are not included in `Get-AzNetworkServiceTag` as explained in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking). So, I have to use the [ServiceTags JSON-file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) that Microsoft publishes.

Technically, no biggie: just fetching content from a JSON-file instead of a cmdlet's output. If it wasn't for the JSON-file to contain unexpected values.

When using `Get-AzLocation` to determine the regions in my geography, this is returned:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzLocation | Where-Object {$_.GeographyGroup -eq 'Europe'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Location'
northeurope
swedencentral
uksouth
westeurope
francecentral
germanywestcentral
italynorth
norwayeast
polandcentral
switzerlandnorth
francesouth
germanynorth
norwaywest
switzerlandwest
ukwest
```

But the ServiceTags_Public_20230925.json uses different values. For example:

```
# Gets latest list of Azure IP ranges from Microsoft
$JsonFileUrl = 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/D/71D86715-5596-4529-9B13-DA13A5DE5B63/ServiceTags_Public_20230925.json'
$JsonFileName = "ServiceTags_Public_20230925.json"

# Download file
$null = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $JsonFileUrl -OutFile $JsonFileName

# Parse file as JSON-object
$Json = Get-Content -LiteralPath $JsonFileName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

# Return unique region names in geography 'Europe'
$Json.values.properties | Where-Object {$_.region -like '*germany*'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty region -Unique | Where-Object -Property region -like '*germany*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty region -Unique

# Result:
germanyn
germanywc
```

So `germanywestcentral` in Get-AzLocation seems to be `germanywc` in the JSON-file. But also: `germanynorth` equals to `germanyn`. And `francecentral` = `centralfrance` and `francesouth` = `southfrance` and `norwayeast` = `norwaye`, etc.

But `ukwest` = `ukwest` and `westeurope` = `westeurope` so they are not all useless...

Obviously, I need these values to be identical to do the automation stuff. Does anyone know how to get this right? Am I looking at the wrong place (Get-AzLocation) for proper mapping?

Answer (score 1):

*I modified your script as below to achieve the requirement.*

Initially, I stored all of the regional mappings in an array called `mapping`and then fetched them as showed. Once it's done, you can retrieve the object `address prefixes` from it.

```
$JsonFileUrl = 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/D/71D86715-5596-4529-9B13-DA13A5DE5B63/ServiceTags_Public_20230925.json'
$JsonFileName = "ServiceTags_Public_20230925.json"
$null = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $JsonFileUrl -OutFile $JsonFileName
$Json = Get-Content -LiteralPath $JsonFileName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$mapping = @{
    'germanywestcentral' = 'germanywc'
    'germanynorth' = 'germanyn'
    'francecentral' = 'centralfrance' #Add all the remaining locations in the same way
}
$regiontranslate = $mapping['germanynorth']
$Json.values.properties | Where-Object {$_.region -like $regiontranslate} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty addressprefixes -Unique
```

*Output:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hash-table suggestion! I understand that I can resolve the naming differences using hard-coded translations. I'm affraid I didn't write my question clear enough. What I really want to know is: why am I seeing different names for the same regions in the first place? Is it an unintended inconcistency by Microsoft or am I using the wrong tool (Get-AzLocation) to determine the locations to search for in the JSON-file?

Comment: That is because of the difference of hosting location by Azure DevOps Microsoft-hosted Agents & general service tag locations. This is a default behavior implemented by them. @Geert

Comment: Thank you @Jahnavi. Appreciate your clarification! Do you happen to know if there is an online reference that contains all the locations, scoped by Azure Geography? It would be great if I can fetch this mapping from some Microsoft-managed list. Rather than having to maintain it myself, which would make it more error-prone...

Comment: Refer these [doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/geographic-coverage), [doc2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/explore/global-infrastructure/geographies/#overview), [chart](https://azurecharts.com/regions/geos). @Geert

Comment: Just to update on this topic. I have asked the same question at the Microsoft Learn forum. Somebody is looking into it. Awaiting further information...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1378058/region-names-ids-in-servicetags-public-*-json-are?comment=question#newest-question-comment